# Subselect in the ON clause

Tags: sql, db2

*Please dont bash me if there are already answers for this question, but I found none.*

Basically I want to make a subselect in the `ON` clause of a `Left join` to get the newest entry in a timeframe.

(start and endtime are timestamps, hardcoded, in local variables or host variables in a Cobol program) to simplify I used integers in that question.

```
Select * from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on 
t1.primary = t2.secondary
and t2.timestamp = (
    select max(t2a.timestamp) from table2 as t2a
        where t2.primary = t2a.primary 
            and t2a.timestamp > starttime
            and t2a.timestamp < endtime
    )
```

Now this does not work, I get the following error:

> AN ON CLAUSE IS INVALID. SQLCODE=-338

Because [(see the docs)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n338.html)

> The ON clause cannot contain a subquery.

Now what we can do to surround that is instead of joining `table2` to join a already delimited subquery. But that surrounds the query optimizer what literally kills the performance:

```
Select * from table1 as t1
left join (
    select t2a.secondary from table2 as t2a
        where t2a.timestamp = (
            select max(t2b.timestamp)
            from table2 as t2b
            where t2a.primary = t2b.primary 
            and t2b.timestamp > starttime
            and t2b.timestamp < endtime
        )
    )as t2
on t1.primary = t2.secondary
```

Any idea how to slove this?

Example data table1:

```
t1.primary 
         1         
         2  
         3
```

Example data table2:

```
t2.primary t2.secondary t2.timestamp
         1            1           4
         2            1           5
         3            1          10
         4            2           4
         5            2           5
```

Variables:

```
starttime = 3
endtime   = 6
```

Expected result:

```
t1.primary t2.primary t2.secondary t2.timestamp
         1          2            1           5  --Leftjoined the newest entry in range
         2          5            2           5 
         3       NULL         NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
select *
from table1 t1
left join (
   select t2.primary, t2.secondary, t2.timestamp,
          row_number() over (partition by t2.secondary order by t2.timestamp desc) rn
   from table2 t2
   where t2.timestamp between starttime and endtime
) t on t1.primary = t.secondary and t.rn = 1
```

If you have an index `table2(timestamp, secondary, primary)` or at least `table2(timestamp, secondary)` then it should run really fast. Without the indexes, it still works with quite good performance, since it leads to one sequential scan of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

something like this.  Just typed in before lunch so don't bash me if it doesn't work.

```
select * from table1 a left join 
(select t2b.primary, max(t2b.timestamp) mxts
            from table2 t2b
            group by t2b.primary
) as b on a.primary = b.primary
left join table2 on b.primary = table2.secondary and 
table2.timestamp = mxts and table2.timestamp between mystartts and myendts
```

NOte: Don't assume timestamps are unique and can be used to extract the last entry from a table because this will undobtly fraile.

Comment: Timestamps per `secondary` are unique, there is a unique constraint on them. But nevertheless this won't work, you can not match `table1.primary` onto `table2.primary`. But I may see your point